# Can these group of statements be reduced or optimized?

Tags: verilog

First block of code:

```
reg [9:0] buffer [18:0];
...
...
buffer[10] = 10'd0;
buffer[11] = 10'd0;
buffer[12] = 10'd0;
buffer[13] = 10'd0;
buffer[14] = 10'd0;
buffer[15] = 10'd0;
buffer[16] = 10'd0;
buffer[17] = 10'd0;
buffer[18] = 10'd0;
```

I tried to reduce it with this line,

```
buffer[10:18] = {10'd0,10'd0,10'd0,10'd0,10'd0,10'd0,10'd0,10'd0};
```

but getting this error

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:698 - Part-select of memory buffer is not allowed.
ERROR:HDLCompiler:1373 - Unpacked value/target cannot be used in assignment.
```

Second Block of Code:

```
input [99:0] image,
...
reg [9:0] buffer [18:0]; 
...
buffer[9] = image[9:0];
buffer[8] = image[19:10];
buffer[7] = image[29:20];
buffer[6] = image[39:30];
buffer[5] = image[49:40];
buffer[4] = image[59:50];
buffer[3] = image[69:60];
buffer[2] = image[79:70];
buffer[1] = image[89:80];
buffer[0] = image[99:90];
```

My alternative was:

```
for (i=0;i<10;i=i+1)
    buffer[9-i] = image[(10*(i+1))-1:10*i];
```

but getting this error

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:44 - i is not a constant
```

Should I be using parameter to define a constant value?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is to use the `generate` statement, because the loop index i is supposed to run at compile-time, not at run-time (i.e. during synthesis, but not to be synthesized).

Comment: This does not require `generate`, just the correct syntax for selecting part ranges as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18068296/97073).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll help you,

```
integer i;

always @ (*)
begin
for (i=1;i<=10;i=i+1)
    buffer[10-i] = image[(i*10 -1) -: 10];
end
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but I guess since I want image[9:0], it should be image [(i*10 -1) -: 10]; as shown in the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18068296/97073)

Comment: oh yes, its typo.